# How can I clone a class with all created functions empty

Tags: python, python-3.x

Say we have a function `f` which takes an argument `p` defaulting to `None`:

```
def f(p = None): ...
```

If `p` is provided it is expected to be an object of a class `C` with certain member functions. This leads us to repeat code like

```
if p is not None: p.f()
```

This is tedious and error prone. Instead of choosing `None` as default for `p` we would rather have a clone of `C` with all member functions doing nothing. We could then just write

```
def f(p = Cc()):
    p.f()
    ...
```

where `Cc` is the clone of `C`.
If `p` is an object of the cloned class the call does nothing, if `p` is provided by the caller the corresponding `f` gets called.
How can we automatically create such a clone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem can be solved by defining a decorator class like this:

```
import inspect

class MockDec:
    def __init__(self, base):
        self.base_func_names = {v[0] for v in inspect.getmembers(base, predicate=inspect.isfunction)
                                if not v[0].startswith('__')}
    
    def __call__(self, cls):
        def pss(*argc, **argv):
            pass
        cls_func_names = {v[0] for v in inspect.getmembers(cls, predicate=inspect.isfunction)
                          if not v[0].startswith('__')}
        for n in self.base_func_names - cls_func_names:
            setattr(cls, n, pss)
        return cls
```

Here `base_func_names` and `cls_func_names` are python sets containing all function names defined in `base` and `cls`. In the `for` loop functions are added to `cls` such that these just call `pss`, which does nothing. Expression `self.base_func_names - cls_func_names` is a set difference. Functions defined in `base` are therefore only added to `cls` if they are not already defined in `cls`.

Here is an example for how the decorator can be used. First define a class `C1`:

```
class C1:
    def __init__(self):
        print( "C1.__init__" )
        
    def f1(self, i):
        print( f"C1.f1({i})" )
        
    def f2(self, i):
        print( f"C1.f2({i})" )
```

and clone `C1` using `MockDec`:

```
@MockDec(base=C1)
class C2:
    def __init__(self):
        print( "C2.__init__" )
        
    def f2(self, i):
        print( f"C2.f2({i})" )
    
c1 = C1()
c1.f1(7)
c1.f2(9)

c2 = C2()
c2.f1(nonsense="nothing") #1
c2.f2(19) #2
```

This results in output

```
C1.__init__
C1.f1(7)
C1.f2(9)
C2.__init__
C2.f2(19)
```

Obviously, `C2` provides a function `f1` which does nothing when called at `#1`. The definition of `f2` remains unchanged by the decorator as shown at `#2`.

Comment: As good as your decorator class seems, I fail to see how it solves the problem when calling `f(p=None)`.

Comment: @quamrana Write `f(p=C2())` for the example above.

Comment: Ok, you mean create the function `def f(p=C2()): ...` and call with `f()`